# Entity Framework 6: Two unrelated entities mapped to same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I want to map one table to two unrelated entities: EntityBasic and EntityAdvanced.
EntityAdvanced has extra business logic that I don't need for this one feature, and I would like to make a new Entity that only has fields from the table.

MyTable:

```
MyTableId : Guid
ParentId : Guid
Name : string
Description : string
Type : int
```

EntityBasic:

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public class EntityBasic
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MyTableId { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentId { get; set }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual List<EntityBasic> Entities{ get; set; }
}
```

EntityAdvanced:

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public class EntityAdvanced
{
    private List<EntityAdvanced> _entities;
    private List<Filter> _filters;

    [Key]
    public Guid MyTableId { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentId { get; set }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual List<EntityAdvanced> Entities
    {
        get { //Some complicated getter }
        set { //Some complicated setter }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get { //Some complicated getter }
        set { //Some complicated setter }
    }

    public void SetFilters(//Some parameters)
    {
        //Some logic 
    }
}
```

When I do this i get this error:

> The entity types 'EntityAdvanced' and 'EntityBasic' cannot share table 'MyTable' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Make `EntityAdvanced` inherit and build upon `EntityBasic`. That will satisfy the "same type hierarchy"

Answer (score 1):

As a base start, your `EntityAdvanced` should inherit EntityBasic since they share the same base set of properties. You don't need to rewrite them. Note the `extends EntityBasic`.

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public class EntityBasic
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MyTableId { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentId { get; set }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual List<EntityBasic> Entities{ get; set; }
}

[NotMapped]
public class EntityAdvanced : EntityBasic
{    
    //[NotMapped]
    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get { //Some complicated getter }
        set { //Some complicated setter }
    }

    public void SetFilters(//Some parameters)
    {
        //Some logic 
    }
}
```

Using inheritence, `List<EntityBasic> Entities` could reference `EntityAdvanced` objects so you don't need anymore to declare:

```
[ForeignKey("ParentId")]
public virtual List<EntityAdvanced> Entities
{
    get { //Some complicated getter }
    set { //Some complicated setter }
}
```

You can get usefull information about implementing inheritence with Entity Framework [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Happy coding!

Comment: When I do that I get this error: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.

Comment: See edits. The fix is pretty simple, you should add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to the child class

Comment: There are parts of the appliction that uses EntityAdvanced, and as expected if I add NotMapped to it, this happens: "The type 'EntityAdvanced' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject." Are there any other options or do I have to find some other solution?